# Unable to access Method with argument list in View Page defined in Model page in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

app/views/users/doc_request.html.erb :

```
<% @docs.each do |doc| %>
    <%= link_to 'Approve', User.activate_doctor(doc) %>
<% end %>
```

app/Model/user.rb :

```
def self.activate_doctor(doc)
  doc.active = 1   #simply setting the value of one column to 1.
end
```

it's throwing error

```
NoMethodError in Users#doc_request
Showing /home/ajay/Desktop/10th Spet/app/views/users/doc_request.html.erb where line #16 raised:
undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write in your model:

```
use doc.activate_doctor

def activate_doctor
  update_attributes(:active => true)
end
```

so that it will save the updated value. I am assuming `active` is a boolean field.

Answer (score 2):

Am I right, that "active" is an attribute of user? If yes, I would change that to an instance method.

Change the line in the view to:

```
doc.activate_doctor
```

And in the model

```
def activate_doctor
  self.active = 1 # if the colum is an integer
  self.active = true # if the column is a boolean
  self.update_attribute(active, 1) # if you want to update the value directly
end
```